# Sabre dev studio soapUI tests authentication

Tags: soapui, sabre

SOAP Basics - environments section on the Sabre Dev Studio (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/environments) says "After you register with Sabre® , you receive test authentication credentials and authorization to use the APIs you selected."

Does this apply to using the soapUI Test Client? I downloaded the test client and the project properties in soapUI is asking for a different set of authentication parameters (username, password, organization) than what was given to me after registration (client id, client secret).

Also, the default endpoint I see inside soapUI tests is https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc , and the web documentation show a different endpoint for customer acceptance testing and nothing for the client development environment.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The client id and secret are just test credentials meant for testing some REST services, specifically the ones found here: https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs

The credentials you mentioned there are the ones that you will get when you sign a contract with Sabre. Those credentials will look a lot more to what seek. Should you want more information on that, you should go to: https://developer.sabre.com/contact, and select the subject: "I want to become a Sabre customer".

Lastly, the URL you reference there is one that still works, but eventually will not. Because the new one works with TLS 1.2 and forward, so it does not work with TLS 1.0, 1.1 nor SSL, for security reasons.
Should you want to know more, please check this: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/security/pci_mandate